# MongoDB aggregate() error in server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two queries, the first one shows `'not master and slaveOk=false'` error and second one works fine in the server. We have two MongoDB replica sets. Can anybody explain why the queries behave so?

```
Product.aggregate(query).exec().then(null, handleMongooseError);
```

and

```
Product.aggregate(query).read('secondaryPrefered').exec().then(null, handleMongooseError);
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB inherently allows only read operation on secondary menber of  replica-set, so when you executed first query it on secondary it must be allowed during connection as slaveOK=true to allow read operations.Hence your second query executed.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/)

Comment: The find() works perfectly without setting read preference but aggregate() only works when preference is set to 'secondaryprefered'. Is aggregate() always hitting slave data set?

Comment: no that is not the case, if you are connected to secondary replica-set you need slaveOK is necessary . When you say "secondaryprefered" it tells mongoose to perform query on secondary. it would be helpfull if you provide code where you create mongoose connection to better understand your problem.